# Html - Div Table - The background colors not working with margins, padding, border

Tags: html, margin, padding, css-tables

This question is easiest asked by showing a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/jaa17/E8Skp/

```
<body style="width:100%; height: 100%; padding: 0 0 0 0; margin: 0 0 0 0; overflow: hidden; background:#999999">
    <p>I want the red/green of the table's/row's background showing through on the left and the right, not the body's background grey. (Note the 10 pixel padding in the table's row/column.)</p>
    <p>And what has happened to the padding on the right? That needs to be red/green too.</p>
    <p>And these blue sections should be on the same line.</p>
    <p>What do I use, margins, borders, padding???? Nothing seems to work.</p>
    <div style="width:100%; height: 100%;">
        <!-- A Div Table -->
        <div style="text-align: center; width: 100%; display:block; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;       background-color: #FF0000;">
            <!-- Row -->
            <div style="text-align: center; width: 100%; display:block; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background-color: #00FF00;">
                <!-- Column -->
                <div style="float: left; width: 50%; display:block; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background-color: #0000FF;">
                    <button type="button">Some Html Stuff</button>
                </div>
                <!-- Column -->
                <div style="float: left; width: 50%; display:block; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background-color: #9999FF;">
                    <button type="button">Some Html Stuff</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want the red/green of the table's/row's background showing through on the left and the right, not the body's background grey. (Note the 10 pixel padding in the table's row/column.)

And what has happened to the padding on the right? That needs to be red/green too.

And these blue sections should be on the same line.

What do I use, margins, borders, padding? Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wackiest answer, but it works. Question and solution provided on my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaa17/E8Skp/

Divs which are containers consider themselves to have zero height, and consequently show no color. To fool them you must put a overflow:hidden or float:left on the CONTAINER div's style. (Note the column needs a float:left due to its positioning in the table and not due to this container-div issue.) A better explanation is given here:

http://netweaver.com.au/floatHouse/

Also the problem with columns not appearing on the same line was due to needing the padding width to be taken off the 100% width, so I used the calc function for all the browsers.

```
<!-- A Div Table -->
<div style="overflow: hidden; text-align: center; width: 100%; width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px); width: -moz-calc(100% - 20px); width: calc(100% - 20px); display:block; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background-color: #FF0000;">
    <!-- Row -->
    <div style="overflow: hidden; text-align: center; width: 100%; width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px); width: -moz-calc(100% - 20px); width: calc(100% - 20px);display:block; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background-color: #00FF00;">
        <!-- Column -->
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%; width: -webkit-calc(50% - 20px); width: -moz-calc(50% - 20px); width: calc(50% - 20px);display:block; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background-color: #0000FF;">
            <button type="button">Some Html Stuff</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Column -->
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%; width: -webkit-calc(50% - 20px); width: -moz-calc(50% - 20px); width: calc(50% - 20px); display:block; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; background-color: #9999FF;">
            <button type="button">Some Html Stuff</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```